# How do I exclude a certain groovy file from being compiled in gradle?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I want to exclude a certain groovy script file from being compiled in the following example, how would I do that? Also I still want to package the file in the fatJar though

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }  }
with jar
}
```

Comment: Stick it in src/main/resources?

Comment: Cool! Added it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the file in

```
src/main/resources
```

It won't be compiled, but it should still be part of any jar task